# ActionBar-PulltoRefresh, wrong header offset when setting the activity to fullscreen

Tags: android, fullscreen, pull-to-refresh

I am using ActionBar-PulltoRefresh by Chris Banes, it is a great libary to have.

However, I run into a weird problem when I set my activity to fullscreen. I set auto-refresh in the onResume() function, where I also show the progress bar animation.

However, sometimes(esp. when come back from the screen lock) the status bar take some time to hide(there is a short animation), and the header and the progress bar  were overlaid in wrong location, i.e. below the real location of the action bar. The offset seems to be exact the size of the status bar.

However, if I trigger the refresh a few seconds later after the activity is fully shown, there is no problem. But I don't want to add a fix delay to the auto-refresh operation in onResume().

Any better fix for this problem?